# R- Using incremental variable as new list entry value

Tags: r

I am trying to use a variable to count the number of occurrences that each string in a preset list occurs in my data. The idea I tried was to have a double for loop, iterating over each string and then running that string through all of the data, and if the substring appears then increment the counter.

```
 statesList <- list("AL","AR","AZ","CA","CO","CT","DE","FL","GA","IA","ID", "IL","IN","KS","KY","LA","MA","MD","ME","MI","MN","MO","MS","MT","NC","ND","NE","NH","NJ","NM","NV","NY", "OH","OK","OR","PA","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VA","VT","WA","WI","WV","WY")
 statesAmount <- list()
 for(state in statesList)
 {
   x <- 0
     for(values in flu["location"])
     {
        if(grepl(state,values))
           x <- x + 1
     }

    statesAmount[[state]] <- x
  }
```

The problem I am having is that the increment variable **"x"**  applies the value to all the entries when it is changed. Does R have anything similar to a **"new"** keyword to avoid this, or what would generally be the best approach to something like this. Would I also be able to convert this list to a data frame later?

EDIT:

```
    location
1   Fort Worth, TX
2   Washington, D.C.
3   Boston, MA
4   Annapolis, MD
5   Brooklyn, NY
6   New York, NY
```

Comment: give a `dput` of your data value, in order us to try

Comment: @denis I added a snippet of the data, as there are over 10,000 rows. The value in "location" can appear as anything which is why I am running it against the predefined list a state abbreviations.

Comment: i edites my answer below, that seem to work. Check it and don't hesitate to accept if it suits you

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With you Location exmaple: You can use the length of grep to know how many occurence, and use lapply instead of a for loop to directly create a list:

```
statesAmount <-data.frame( count = sapply(statesList,function(state){
  length(grep(state,location))
}), state = unlist(statesList))

   count state
1      0    AL
2      0    AR
3      0    AZ
4      0    CA
5      0    CO
6      0    CT
7      0    DE
8      0    FL
9      0    GA
10     0    IA
11     0    ID
12     0    IL
13     0    IN
14     0    KS
15     0    KY
16     0    LA
17     1    MA
18     1    MD
19     0    ME
20     0    MI
21     0    MN
22     0    MO
23     0    MS
24     0    MT
25     0    NC
26     0    ND
27     0    NE
28     0    NH
29     0    NJ
30     0    NM
31     0    NV
32     2    NY
33     0    OH
34     0    OK
35     0    OR
36     0    PA
37     0    RI
38     0    SC
39     0    SD
40     0    TN
41     1    TX
42     0    UT
43     0    VA
44     0    VT
45     0    WA
46     0    WI
47     0    WV
48     0    WY
```